# BIDSHelper2014 1.7.0.0 (BimlEngine) throws <>z__Aspects

Tags: c#, etl, biml

I have a code which works fine with 1.6.6 version. For example this line:

```
var root = new AstRootNode(null);
```

I decided to update the library to 1.7.0.0 and now I get "The type initializer for '<>z__Aspects' threw an exception.". If someone else faced this problem, please help solve it.

Inner Exception:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'Utility, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Utility, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}
```

Stack Trace:

```
   at Varigence.Utility.ComponentModel.VulcanNotifyPropertyChanged..ctor()
   at Varigence.Languages.Biml.AstNode..ctor(IFrameworkItem parentItem)
   at Varigence.Languages.Biml.AstRootNode..ctor(IFrameworkItem parentItem)
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Nikolai\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 14
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: `<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
<#
var root = new AstRootNode(null);
#>
</Biml>` works for me. 1.7 on VS 2012. Perhaps you've oversimplified the problem domain? (my 2014 installation is banjaxed or I'd have run it  on there)

Comment: Wow, it works for you, perhaps I do something wrong (but 1.6.6 was installed the same way and works like a charm). I downloaded the zip from here https://bidshelper.codeplex.com/releases/view/137336. Then just added reference to BimlEngine.dll. That's it.

Comment: Perhaps it was picking my Mist/BimlStudio installation? I'll see if I run into an instance with a pristine install at some point

Comment: My efforts were on several computers...So it would be good if you see.

Comment: Coming in late... Were you trying to use BimlEngine.dll from outside of BIDSHelper?